# Why is "sort -u" omitting some unique lines in my file?

Tags: sorting, unix, cjk

- The context
- The question
- System information

  - file
  - locale
  - `sort` version
  - Package manager

## The context

Consider the following file named `main.txt`

```
line 1
䔍
䏝
line 4
line 5 䏝
```

As you can see above, the file contains 5 unique lines. The lines no. 3 and no. 5 contain the same character: "䏝" (U+43DD).

If I execute `sort -u` in the file I get the following result.

```
sort -u main.txt
```

```
䔍
line 1
line 4
line 5 䏝
```

As you can see above, line no. 3, whose content is `䏝`, is not shown as a result even though it is a unique line.

## The question

Why is `sort -u` not including line no. 3 as a result even though it is a unique line?

## System information

### file

In my system, the output of running `file` in `main.txt` is shown below.

```
file main.txt
```

```
main.txt: Unicode text, UTF-8 text
```

### locale

This is the output of the `locale` command in my system.

```
locale
```

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

### `sort` version

```
sort --version
```

```
sort (GNU coreutils) 9.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

### Package manager

The `sort` binary is owned by the `coreutils` package.

```
pacman -Q -o "$(which sort)"
```

```
/usr/bin/sort is owned by coreutils 9.1-1
```

The following is the information of the `coreutils` package that has been installed locally.

```
pacman -Q -i coreutils
```

```
Name            : coreutils
Version         : 9.1-1
Description     : The basic file, shell and text manipulation utilities of the GNU operating system
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/
Licenses        : GPL3
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : glibc  acl  attr  gmp  libcap  openssl
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : base  ca-certificates-utils  dkms  java-runtime-common  linux  mkinitcpio  p11-kit  pacman  util-linux
Optional For    : usbutils
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 15.24 MiB
Packager        : Sébastien Luttringer <seblu@seblu.net>
Build Date      : Sun 17 Apr 2022 01:21:13 PM -05
Install Date    : Thu 28 Apr 2022 12:14:56 AM -05
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

Comment: About debugging *sort* source code? :) Looks like a locale problem. Try to replace en_US with zh_CN (install Chinese if not present).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. For the record, here's how I changed the locale in Arch Linux. I opened the file `/etc/locale.gen` and uncommented the line that contained `zh_CN.UTF-8 UTF-8`. Then, I executed `sudo locale-gen`. Then, I confirmed that the locale for Chinese was installed by executing `locale -a`. `zh_CN.utf8` was listed when executing `locale -a`. Finally, I executed the command `$ LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 sort -u main.txt` and line no. 3 was shown. Note that I didn't need to change the locale for my entire system.

Comment: You could simply store the *locale* lines into a file F then do in a shell `source F` before doing `sort`...  Nicely presented question, but it's more for the Linux/Unix or AskUbuntu SE sites rather than here on SO...

Comment: @Déjàvu You are right, my bad. While I'm aware of Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, I completely forgot of that site when deciding the appropriate site to post (perhaps, because I haven't visited that site for a long  time). I'll keep it in mind for my next questions related to Unix & Linux.

Comment: By the way, found another scenario. Replace `䔍` with `` and `䏝` with `` in the file above and execute `sort -u main.txt`. The same issue happens, now line no. 3 containing `` is not shown even when using `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8`. I tried using other locales that started with `zh_CN.` and noticed that these two issues are solved when using `zh_CN.GBK` or `zh_CN.GB18030` as values for `$LANG`. I'm newbie when it comes to locales, so trial and error is my only tool. I should read more docs on this.

Comment: @Déjàvu I found some other issues when changing the locale. I posted [a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723492) on that in Unix & Linux SE.